# R: Why is expand.grid() producing many more rows than I expect?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-wrangling

My understanding is that `base::grid.expand()` and `tidyr::grid_expand()` will return an object with a row for each unique value of the joint distribution of unique values across one or more vectors. For example, here is what I expect:

```
# Preliminaries
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)

# Simulate data
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(rep(c(1,2), 50)), y= as.factor(sample(1:3, 100, replace = T)))

# Expected result
data.frame(x = rep(1:2, 3), y = rep(1:3, 2)) # 6 rows!
```

However, when I actually use the functions, I get many more (duplicated) rows than I expect:

```
# Tidyverse result
tidyr::expand_grid(df) # produces 100 rows!
tidyr::expand_grid(df$x, df$y) # produces 10k rows!

# Base R version
base::expand.grid(df) # produces 10k rows!
base::expand.grid(df$x, df$y) # produces 10k rows!

# Solution...but why do I have to do this?!
unique(base::expand.grid(df))
```

Can someone explain what I am missing about what it is supposed to do?

Comment: In my mind, `expand.grid` expands every combination of every value in each of the vectors (columns) passed to it. Every. Combination. Period. It is assumed that you know what you're doing, so `expand.grid(c(1,1,2,3), c(1,2,3,3))` is never inferred to mean `expand.grid(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3))`. If you want uniqueness in your input or output, lacking design-arguments in the functions, you need to control it yourself.

Comment: `expand.grid` expands two vectors x and y of lengths L1 and L2 into a grid of L1 times L2 "coordinate" pairs. Unique pairs, instead, are returned by `combn(c(x, y), 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid` makes no attempt to return only unique values of the input vectors. It will always output a data frame which has a number of rows that is the same as the product of the length of its input vectors:

```r
nrow(expand.grid(1:10, 1:10, 1:10))
#> [1] 1000

nrow(expand.grid(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
#> [1] 1
```

If you look at the source code for `expand.grid`, it takes the variadic dots and turns them into a list called `args`. It then includes the line:

```r
d <- lengths(args)
```

which returns a vector with one entry for each vector that we feed into `expand.grid`. In the case of `expand.grid(df$x, df$y)`, `d` would be equivalent to `c(100, 100)`.

There then follows the line

```r
orep <- prod(d)
```

which gives us the product of `d`, which is 100x100, or 10,000.

The variable `orep` is used later in the function to repeat each vector so that its length is equal to the value `orep`.

If you only want unique combinations of the two input vectors, then you must make them `unique` at the input to `expand.grid`.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because it answers the question directly. However, @akrun's answer is excellent because it provides different ways of producing what I was expecting. Ideally, these would be combined :/

Answer (score 3):

The input to `expand_grid` is variadic (`...`), we can use `do.call`

```
do.call(expand_grid, df)
```

Or with `invoke`

```
library(purrr)
invoke(expand_grid, df)
# A tibble: 10,000 × 2
   x     y    
   <fct> <fct>
 1 1     3    
 2 1     3    
 3 1     3    
 4 1     2    
 5 1     3    
 6 1     2    
 7 1     2    
 8 1     2    
 9 1     3    
10 1     1    
# … with 9,990 more rows
```

Or with `!!!`

```
expand_grid(!!! df)
# A tibble: 10,000 × 2
   x     y    
   <fct> <fct>
 1 1     3    
 2 1     3    
 3 1     3    
 4 1     2    
 5 1     3    
 6 1     2    
 7 1     2    
 8 1     2    
 9 1     3    
10 1     1    
# … with 9,990 more rows
```

---

As @Mossa commented, the function to return unique combinations would be `expand` or `crossing` because `expand` calls `expand_grid` on `unique` values

```
> expand(df, df)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  x     y    
  <fct> <fct>
1 1     1    
2 1     2    
3 1     3    
4 2     1    
5 2     2    
6 2     3
```

Based on the source code

```
getAnywhere("expand.data.frame")
function (data, ..., .name_repair = "check_unique") 
{
    out <- grid_dots(..., `_data` = data)
    out <- map(out, sorted_unique)
    out <- expand_grid(!!!out, .name_repair = .name_repair)
    reconstruct_tibble(data, out)
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with `tidyr::expand`?

Comment: @Mossa In `expand`, the first argument is data followed by `...` or variadic.  `expand(df, x, y)` or `expand(df, df)` or `expand(df, !!! df)` or with `crossing` `crossing(df)`

Comment: No, that doesn't work for me. Can you try it yourself please?

Comment: I believe `tidyr::expand` would be the right answer, because it is an API for data-frames and not vectors, like `expand_grid`/`expand.grid` are.. But I cannot make it work.

Comment: @Mossa All of those creates the output and there was no error.  But the output number of rows is 6.  It is not clear what you meant by `doesn't work`

Comment: @Mossa I get `expand(df, df)#
# A tibble: 6 × 2...`

Comment: @Mossa if you check the source code of `expand`, it does make unique values and then calll expand_grid `out <- map(out, sorted_unique);
    out <- expand_grid(!!!out, .name_repair = .name_repair)`

Comment: that's not very good. But thanks.

Comment: @Mossa The function behavior?

Comment: I think the concern was that the (df,df) input was not producing an object with sufficient rows: z <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = 1:4); tidyr::expand(z, z); tidyr::expand(z, x, y)

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening: I think the issue is that in one case all unique ROWS are returned, in another all unique combinations of values across columns are returned.